# Geoserver global services and GeoWebCache

Tags: geoserver, tiles, geowebcache

I have disabled the "global setting" in my Geoserver to require the workspace name in all URL endpoint.

Unfortunately, GeoWebCache does not work anymore.
It can return the tiles allready generated but cannot generate new tile with geoserver.

It say "400: Problem communicating with GeoServer"
For example :

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/adm_ws/gwc/service/wmts?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetTile&VERSION=1.0.0&LAYER=adm3&[...]

Do you have any idea to solve this problem ? 
Geoserver V2.13.1
GeoWebCache V1.13.1

Answer (score 1):

You will need to configure Geowebcache to use the new end points. I don't think it can do that via the gui so you will need to edit the configuration file directly.

Comment: In geowebcache.xml ? I don't find how to specify the workspace name in the URL End points for Geowebcache.